# Align UI elements vertically in (Materialize) CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to create a UI with "lots of controls", that are somewhat densely packed together vertically. I'm currently using Materialize which by default makes horizontally stacked forms look quite nice, but vertically stacking different types of UI elements looks terrible by default. An example:

[image]

In this example I would like the buttons to be aligned with the box of the dropdown menu, or for the label above the dropdown to float above the invisible upper line that the buttons are aligned to. But my question is not about this specific case, I show this to illustrate a problem I'm generally having with Materialize in this type of UI.

It would be possible to specify an exact number of pixels to every element class's margin that would force things to be aligned. But then it seems I'm kind of fighting against the defaults every step of the way.

My question: **How to make good looking vertically aligned UI elements?**

(It doesn't have to use Materialize if some other CSS framework solves this much better.)

Comment: This may be solvable using flexbox's align items. What does the code look like?

Comment: @AshleyHoward It's a <div class="row" which contains the buttons and dropdown menu as <div class="col . Is that enough code? I can add example code to my question, but I chose not to because I wanted to keep it somewhat more general than being about those specific elements in my example. But if you want I'll add it.